# Is there any method to get cart details inside a plugin feature in Magento 2

Tags: cart, shipping, magento-2.1.3, plugin

How can I **get cart products in a custom module plugin** in magento 2 on before-save shipping info hear already i'm taking the customer address its working fine like this i need to get the cart products also

> /app/code/Sem/Shipment/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
         <?php

namespace Sem\Shipment\Plugin\Checkout\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{

    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $jsonResultFactory;
    protected $_quote;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
          $this->_quote= $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation

    )
    {

     $cart = $this->_quote->create()->get($cartId);
    $items = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
    $resulta = [];
    if (count($items) > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item)
            $resulta[] = $item->getName();
    }
    //print_r($resulta);
    $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $postcode = $address->getData('postcode');
    $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
    throw new StateException(__($resulta[0]));              
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just assume you need to echo the product name only. If you need other fields, please let me know.

In your custom module PHP function:

```
protected $_quote;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    /*Other DIs if you have*/
)
{
    $this->_quote= $quoteFactory;
    /*Other DIs  if you have*/
}

public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
){
    //Inside 
    $cart = $this->_quote->create()->get($cartId);
    $items = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
    $result = [];
    if (count($items) > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item)
            $result[] = $item->getName();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: i need full details of product inside the plugin i need to check some details hear

Comment: Can you specify what details you want to include?

Comment: I am trying to check the delivery availability using the zip code for that i fetch the address information using "beforeSaveAddressInformation" method in plugin feature so there i get the delivery pin code now i need to get the seller ZIP(post code) and cart total price product weight etc.. based on the result from hear i need activate the nexr stem (Payment) hear i'm posing my plugin code

Comment: in $items i'm getting empty value

Comment: Try to use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` instead, see my edited codes

Comment: @ PY Yick still i'm getting the same please check my updated code

Comment: See my edited answer. I overlooked the `$cartId` has included into `beforeSaveAddressInformation()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60956/discussion-between-amith-and-py-yick).

Comment: @ PY Yick hear i got number of products in plugin so i need to check each product with their delivery availability if any of the product will not available for delivery it should removed from cart by printing a message in frontend how can i do this?

Comment: You can issue invoice directly with reduced product qty

Comment: @ PY Yick how can i do it do you have any sample code

Comment: can i use this code $this->_session->removeItem($pid)->save();

Comment: Not right. `$this->_session` is just load the session. You have to load current cart by `$this->_session->getQuote()`

Comment: ok thats great its working now i need to display the message in frontend which all are vailable for delivery and which are not available for delivery

Comment: @ PY Yick also if any of product delivery not available then the payment section should disable up to the time the customer remove non delivery available item from cart

Comment: That's the question that out of this scope, you can ask another question

Comment: @ PY Yick  can you answer for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/disable-payment-section-using-plugin-feature-in-magento-2