# Disable payment section using plugin feature in Magento 2

Tags: shipping, payment, magento-2.1.3, plugin

I'm doing some functionality in Magento 2 plugin feature. Here I took the shipping information before saving it and checked the delivery availability. Now I need to prevent the next step payment if the delivery is not available for any of the product.

Comment: Are you going to prevent any specific `payment` Gateway or entire payment section?

Comment: @ Manoj Kumar No i need to prevent whose payment section or i have an other option in this case if delivery not available redirect to cart page

Comment: Maybe observer can help you this time. I think `checkout_submit_before` should be the one you need. https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

Comment: @ PY Yick up to this step checking condition we have done in plugin then how can it possible?